# 100nF MLCC bypass capacitor spontaneously exploding on 3.3V bus, how does this even happen?

Tags: capacitor, soldering, surface-mount, failure

A 1608/0603 multilayer ceramic chip capacitor was functioning as a bypass capacitor for the 3.3V supply of a InvenSense MPU-6050 6 axis (gyro + accelerometer) MEMS sensor. It somehow exploded forming an open circuit, *without* damaging the sensor IC or any other component on the board, and without affecting its operation.

[image: macro photo of blown component]

Illustration of a typical circuit from the InvenSense [datasheet](http://43zrtwysvxb2gf29r5o0athu.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Datasheet1.pdf):

[image: illustrative typical usage of MPU-6050 from the datasheet]

Some parts of the ceramic material are still attached to the PCB and bits of the wreckage are scattered all around. The cap was reflow soldered with lead free solder by the manufacturer and the PCB has not been reworked. I am pretty sure that the component was intact when I first got the board.

I am curious about what failure mode this was, and how to prevent such failures in boards of my own design. Is this a common ocurrence in mass production? I thought these were fairly reliable components.

Comment: What exactly is this PCB used for?  A sensor like an MPU-6050 could be found in a phone, but a more likely usage (for a circuit someone would be asking questions about) is an RC quadcopter or a self balancing unicycle or "hoverboard" - ie, things with high powered motor drives that may be spreading unpleasant pulse loads around a poorly designed board.

Comment: Is this the only unit that failed? It could have been a cracked  cap and partially failed with high ESR and failed completely on load. You will need to investigate to eliminate other failure sources like inductive spikes and significant supply noise . If the capacitor is at fault common causes are flexure (bending), bad component stock, and process defects like too much force on the picknplace or debris on pcb during placement

Comment: The most likely explanation is either a latent fault in the capacitor or mechanical stress resulting in a fracture and layers shorting together.

Comment: On the subject of mechanical stress, is that a PCB support right next to the failed capacitor, on the right of the picture?

Comment: @Chris stratton good guess, it's a naze32 rev5 multicopter flight control board.

Comment: @crasic I don't think it's exposed to large voltage transients as it's on a regulated 3.3V bus, and the regulator is powered with 5V from a buck converter.

Comment: A 4v-rated cap at 3.3v? That sounds like a design oversight. Typically, caps are chosen to have twice the voltage rating for both some margin of safety, and increased performance.

Comment: @jms inductive spikes can exceed supply voltage significantly. You could investigate turn on noise or increase the cap rating if it's a repeated issue in the design.

Comment: Oh yeah thw orientation of the cap, it size, and the massive support member makes this ripe for mechanical stress failure. If this is your design you should research into mlcc flexure limits, they are surprisingly fragile components

Comment: @user1582568  yes, that's a nylon nut on a m3 nylon standoff, but I don't think it's on *that* tight. The board has been exposed to temperature variations (20C -> -20C when taking it outside), could the thermal stress actually crack the caps?

Comment: @rdtsc  I don't know what exact capacitors they actually used, the "schematic" is from the InvenSense datasheet

Comment: Also, how long did the board last before failure?

Comment: @whatroughbeast about an hour

Comment: It's worth pointing out that at 3.3V DC, a 4V rated capacitor may actually lose 50% or more of its rated capacitance. [Here's a neat little document.](http://www.niccomp.com/help/VoltageCoefficientofCapacitors-032012-R1.pdf)

Comment: Given 1 hour of operation before failure, I'd go for infant mortality.  Probably a bad part. The key, of course, is to operate several more boards to see if they also fail quickly. If so, the you should consider either a bad batch of caps or a board problem For instance, if the board support implied by the nylon nut nearby is misaligned, the board might be distorted by the nut and the mechanical stress damaging the cap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could be high ripple currents (or poor cooling and moderate ripple currents) causing overheating. Or it could be one or several of the mechanical stress/defect sort mentioned in the comments, or a combination of such factors. Without knowing if the capacitor is prone to blowing up on more than one copy of the board it's hard to say for sure. Post-mortem analysis of a single failure without extensive supporting data is not definitive.

Linked below is a TDK app note hosted at Digi-Key which pretty much explains that while MLCCs are often not exactly ripple-current rated, ripple currents do affect them - but it's more of a temperature thing than a specific current. They also mention that when ripple currents are measured on MLCCs it's typically at room temperature - so it's quite possible that some lazy designer found a number, ignored the "25°C" associated, and said whoo-hoo, here's my ripple current - let her rip - at 65°C.

http://www.digikey.com/en/pdf/t/tdk/ripple-current-mlccs

The "4V capacitor on 3.3V supply" (also mentioned in comments after I wrote the above) is likewise a poor design choice that may well contribute, but it's unclear if the spec is what the actual capacitor is, since you indicate a source that is evidently not the manufacturer of the board (chipmaker? in which case they are nuts to spec that) for the spec.

Comment: TDK has additional white sheets hosted on digikey about MLCC failures under physical and thermal stress [Common Cracking Modes in Surface Mount MLCC](http://www.digikey.com/en/pdf/t/tdk/common-cracking-modes) and [Guide to MLCC Flex Cracking](http://www.digikey.com/en/pdf/t/tdk/guide-flex-cracking-mlcc)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the part cracked and that will usually cause it to short.  Being on a rail, smoke will be involved.